# Problem with the validation for hangman game

Tags: c++, arrays, validation, char

I'm working on a hangman game for a college asignment and i aleady have most of the work done but for some reason this part here is not working. Is there a problem with my logic? It seems to be incredibly simple.

```
bool second_check(char user_input) {

    char u[3]={'a','r','i'};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        if (user_input==u[i]){
            return true;

        };
    };

    return false;
}
int main(){
    char o;
    cout<<"enter"<<endl;
    cin>>o;


    if (second_check(o)==true) {
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Wrong! \n Strike one!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? `for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {` will go out of bounds though. You'd want `i < 3`.

Comment: You have an array of three elements, what are its valid indexes? What indexes do you use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't edit your question to state that you've figured it out (I rolled back your edit, accordingly). Either post a proper answer explaining what the answer is, or just close the question, since it appears it was just a programming mistake specific to your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop will loop 4 times even though you have 3 elements, causing it to try and access an undefined location in memory, to fix this replace the *'i <=3'* with *'i<3'*

so the for loop should like this in the end:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    if (user_input==u[i]){
        return true;

    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Since `char u[3]={'a','r','i'};` contains only 3 characters, your for loop will be:

`for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)` or

`for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`.

**Explanation**

This is because, in C/C++ and most of the programming language, the array count starts from 0. Therefore the first element will be array[0] and last will array[n-1] where n is the size of the array used at initialization. (Above, n=3)

Answer (score 0):

So it would be helpful to the community if you state clearly what the problem is (i.e expected vs. actual output).

That said, a couple problems I can see...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    if (user_input==u[i]){
```

1. Since `u` is of size 3 (`char user[3]`), you need to change your `for` loop to be `i < 3` since arrays are 0 based, valid indices are `0,1,2` and you will go out of bounds of the array. I.e. `user[3]` is not a valid index.
2. You are not comparing an index of `user_input` which I suspect you want to. i.e. `user_input[i]`.